# how do you convert a generic(Char or Integer) variable into an int in java

Tags: java

T can be either an integer or a char otherwise it should output an error(which is what i want).

My method below is trying to convert the argument from char to int or int to int.

I have no problem if there is no generic and T was int or char but since its not defined, it wont let me compile.

Is there any way to bypass this, or is there another way of converting a generic variable?

Current Code gives error:

```
incompatible types: T cannot be converted to int
        int toReturn = gKey;
```

```java
public class MyClass<T>{
    private int convert(T gKey){
        int toReturn = gKey;
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Edit1: {toReturn instead of 1} I made a mistake and corrected

Edit2: Using the extends Number solution, here are the results that I got

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test 1 for integer argument, should output 1:: success
        Test<Integer> test1 = new Test<>();
        int a = 1;
        System.out.println(test1.convert(a));
        //test 2 for character argument, should output 65 :: failure compile error
        Test<Character> test2 = new Test<>();
        char b = 'A';
        System.out.println(test2.convert(b));
    }
```

Comment: Your value `toReturn` is defined and completely local to the convert method so no other method has access to it.   Thus,  I suspect that is the value you want to eventually return.

Comment: The solution you marked as "the answer" doesn't work. You can create a method that returns an `int` and return a character

Comment: I have tested and it works, I see why you say it doesn't work but the reason it works is because Java allows you to directly assign a char to int which converts it automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use instanceof.

1. If you want to represent any char as it's ASCII code:

```java
private int convert(T gKey) {
 if (gKey instanceof Integer)
    return ((Integer) gKey).intValue();
 else 
   if (gKey instanceof Character)
      return ((Character) gKey).charValue();
   else throw new IllegalArgumentException("IllegalArgumentException");
}
```

2. If you want to process only char witch represents number and convert to such number, not to ASCII code:

```java
private int convert(T gKey) {
  if (gKey instanceof Integer)
     return ((Integer) gKey).intValue();
  else 
    if (gKey instanceof Character)
       try {
            return Integer.parseInt(Character.toString((Character) gKey));
           }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             throw new NumberFormatException ("NumberFormatException ");
           }          
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("IllegalArgumentException");
}
```

Comment: Did you try this solution? This solution doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I checked. What kind of error did you get?

Comment: The `else if` returns a `char` but the method returns an `int`.

Comment: Yep, I get all three of the results I want,
The code below is a way to convert char to int so thats why the else if works
```char a = 'A';
int b = a;```

Comment: I suppose @hfontanez means situations if we pass character wich represents a number, for example '1', and if you need to convert it to 1 int, and not to it's code you may use second solution.

Comment: You are still returning the ASCII conversion in the catch block.

Comment: @BaekhanSung "converting char to int" is too lose of a statement. What are you converting? If the answer is the value, casting the `char` to `int` doesn't work because what you are converting is really the DATA TYPE, not the value. Converting a char value into an int value means taking something like '1' and convert it to 1. That's a VALUE conversion. When you `cast` char to `int` all you're doing is returning the ASCII value of the character. Unless your goal is EXACTLY that, casting is very wrong. Do you understand now? I made this point very clear in my post.

Comment: @hfontanez I corrected the second solution

Answer (score 3):

### convert the argument from char to int

I am assuming that you would like to take a numeric character value such as '1' and convert it into an integer. If so, that's done simply like this:

```
char c = '1';
int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
```

Of course, this conversion only work for numeric characters. Therefore, you must handle exception in some way to deal with cases when the `char` parameter does not represent a number. For example:

```
try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // do something here
}
```

On the other hand, if your intent is to "convert" a `char` into an `int` to get the ASCII value of the character, all you need is to typecast the `char` into an `int`:

```
char c = 'a';
int i = (int) c; // i should be 97 decimal (61 hex)
```

I don't know why you would want that, but it is an alternative based on the plain statement you made of "converting" a `char` to an `int`

### convert the argument from int to int

This should be simply returning the argument. There is no "conversion" required.

### The solution

Since you're using a `T` as an argument, you need to do some checks in in the code.

```
if (arg instanceof Character)
    return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf((char)arg));
if (arg instanceof Integer)
    return (int) arg;
// for all other cases, either throw exception (i.e. `IllegalArgumentException`) or return some erroneous value (i.e. if the expected return value is zero or greater, you could return -1)
```

Comment: I think it's no need to convert arg from char to Integer in thirst case, because as method return int it will be automatically casted from char to int. Check this int i='a';

Comment: Casting is not converting. Read my post. You will understand why..

Comment: Yes, converting. If I do understand what do you mean - if parameter is '1' you try to represent it as 1.

Comment: + from me. Thanx